# Select Unique Values from Different Columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has 5 different columns:

```
vote_1, vote_2, vote_3, vote_4 and vote_5
```

For each row, these columns contain a name and what I am trying to do now is fetch the total number of occurrences of every value in any of the above columns.

The final result should be something like:

```
Value1 | 30

Value2 | 25

.....
```

How to achieve this in a single SQL query?.

Comment: Any time you have enumerated columns (above '2', say) it's probably time to start rethinking your design. (Plus, we have different definitions of 'different')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION` to combine multiple columns into one. Then `GROUP` and `COUNT`.

```
select vote, count(*) as cnt
from (
    select vote_1 as vote from mytable
    union all select vote_2 as vote from mytable
    ..
    union all select vote_N as vote from mytable
) sub
group by vote
```

Comment: @ArtemisChaitidis You can thank him by selecting this as the correct answer.